# Horizontally aligning select fields except label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I align select boxes except for the label, which i want to remain at the top left?

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="SelectDate">Date of Event</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="SelectMonth">
            <option>Jan</option>
            <option>Feb</option>
            <option>Mar</option>
        </select>
        <select class="form-control" id="SelectDay">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>
        <input class="form-control" type="Number" placeholder="Year">
    </div>
</form>
```

This code makes it all aligned but I'm trying to make it look like:

Date

[month][day][year] not

Date [month][day][year]

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this styles to your label:

```
.form-inline label[for="SelectDate"] {
    display: block;
}
```

Now it will display it as you wanted: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLdZgX

Comment: Thank you you're a life saver